# Identification of NullPointerException cause

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

How to identify exactly what causing NullPointerException?

```
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.joericharduz.akita/com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-14 20:25:56.703: E/AndroidRuntime(32491):    ... 11 more
```

Please give your suggestions how to find NullPointerException.

Line 56 code:

```
etSearch.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
```

Comment: Your code maybe ? Or you forgot to add the activity into your Manifest file.

Comment: What have you done to try and find it so far?

Comment: Show us your MainActivity and mark the line 56.

Comment: @mirco.widmer from where you know it is in line 56?

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException... at com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)"

Comment: It says so in the exception: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)

Comment: `NullPointerException` means you are trying to call a method or access a member variable of an object that is null. Some object on line 56 is null.

Comment: I think what you want is `etSearch = findViewById(R.id.etSearch);`. It will be easier to tell if you post the code from your onCreate() method.

Comment: Understood. How to initialize it?

Comment: Inside MainActivity I have this: EditText etSearch;

Comment: Inside OnCreate: etSearch.findViewById(R.id.etSearch); What should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialized etSearch. The proper way to do that is like so:

`etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);`

NOT this: `etSearch.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);`

Make sure you've called setContentView(...) first.

Comment: Yes. I have setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); before etSearch.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);

Comment: So change that line to what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public class MyActivity extends Activity{

EditText et;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourId);
}
}
```

This is the proper way to instantiate the activity element . You are not typecasting the EditText element.